# iOS6 - MKMapView current location blue dot

Tags: mkmapview, ios6, currentlocation

In iOS6 (Google map) I am not seeing the current location which should be marked by a blue dot.

When I run the same code in ios5.1 and previous versions, i am getting the blue dot marked in my current location.

When I was searching for a solution, I discovered that the following line need to be added to get the blue dot, and I am using the same,

```
mapInstance.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

But I still didn't get the blue dot. Is there anything that needs to be added in my code?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following; switch to the Maps Attributes inspector and click the checkbox for Shows User Location.